# Is there a Firefox Add-on that lets you copy and paste Latex from websites?

Tags: firefox, latex

Some websites like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem#Other_simple_resolutions) don't let me copy and paste the Latex.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin that does what you ask, so I made one. Take a look:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/latexcopy/